# Login to Docker Hub from PHP script

Tags: php, docker, command-line-interface

I am trying to login and push Docker images from a PHP script as part of our CICD process. Here is the code:

```
<?php

include '../php/database.php';

$duser = 'username';
$dpass = 'password';
$dmail = 'email';

$tag = 'from system';

function tagImage($tag) {
    $getImageID = "SELECT `imageID` FROM `docker_images` WHERE `tag` = :tag ";
    $params = array(':tag' => $tag);
    $results = dataQuery($getImageID, $params);
    if(!empty($results)) {
        $image = $results[0]['imageID'];
        global $repo = $results[0]['repo']; // I know this is a bad idea, will change it when all else is working
        $last = system("sudo docker tag -f $image $repo 2>&1", $retval);
    }
    return $retval;
}

$tagStatus = tagImage($tag);

if(0 == $tagStatus) {
    echo '<pre>';

    $login = system("sudo docker login --username=$duser", $retval);
    var_dump($login);
    var_dump($retval);
    // push it real good
    $last = system("sudo docker push $repo 2>&1", $retval1);
    var_dump($last);
    var_dump($retval1);
}
?>
```

This returns the following:

```
string(0) ""
int(1)
The push refers to a repository [app/ap-name] (len: 1)
21d623eb89a9: Image push failed

Please login prior to push:
Username: EOF
string(13) "Username: EOF"
int(1)
```

The push is failing because the login is not working from the PHP script, however, when I login from the command line the login is successful.

What am I doing wrong? Can I login to Docker Hub with PHP like this? Or should the technique be different?

**EDIT:** The PHP script will be called via AJAX, effectively making it run as if it were being run from the browser. I am running it from the browser for testing purposes.

Comment: Try `echo "password" | sudo docker login --username $duser  --password-stdin`, might work..

Comment: See docs on it https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#login-to-a-self-hosted-registry the Provide a password using STDIN part

Comment: Dont forget to get rid of the `global` ;p you should know better...

Comment: You saw the comment following the `global` @LawrenceCherone ;)

Comment: Still getting `Please login prior to push: Username: EOF` @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login requires all of the credentials including password and email address associated with the Docker hub repo:

```
$login = system("sudo docker login --username $duser --password $dpass --email $dmail 2>&1", $retval);
var_dump($login);
var_dump($retval);
```

Using this syntax returns the following (expected):

```
WARNING: login credentials saved in /root/.dockercfg.
Login Succeeded
string(15) "Login Succeeded"
int(0)
```

Past that point the `push` works properly and returns no errors.