# SASS compiler not working from exec

Tags: php, sass

In a CentOS container, I am trying to get the SASS to execute from PHP's `exec()`. SASS is executable, I can execute the command successfully from inside the container manually, but not from the PHP.

Command I am trying is:

PHP

```
$command = '/usr/local/bin/sass ' . $webFolderPath . '/styles/style_303.scss' . ' ' . $webFolderPath . '/styles/style_303.css';
$command .= " 2>&1";
echo $command;
exec($command, $output, $return);
```

Translates to:

```
/usr/local/bin/sass /var/www/html/portal/web/styles/style_303.scss /var/www/html/portal/web/styles/style_303.css 2>&1
```

I get the following error.

```
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/path_support.rb:68:in `path=': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/path_support.rb:30:in `initialize'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:357:in `new'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:357:in `paths'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:379:in `path'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:794:in `dirs'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:658:in `each_normal'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:669:in `_all'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:864:in `find'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:864:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:175:in `try_activate'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from <internal:abrt_prelude>:2:in `<compiled>'
```

> Versions:
>
> Sass: 3.5.4 (Bleeding Edge)
>
> Ruby: 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
>
> Gem: 2.0.14.1
>
> CentOS: 7

Any idea, if I am missing something?

Comment: The problem might be, the missing environment variables.

Comment: @Philipp, Like what? Can you give me some details?

Comment: Show your PHP code as well. You mentioned "container"; are you running PHP and SASS/Ruby in Docker containers? How are those set up?

Comment: @AndréDion, I have added the PHP code. Yes in a docker container, the setup explanation might be a lot out of context for the question, what specifically do you want to know? PHP, Ruby, Gem, Sass are all installed in the same container, PHP processes the script after receiving proxy request to `php-fpm` from another  container (the web service)

Comment: @Starx TBH, I don't know SASS but some of the syntax does look similar to Docker, to which someone had a similar problem. If so, you might like to have a look at this Q&A by Jay Blanchard https://stackoverflow.com/q/47997965/1415724

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, Thank you for trying to help. But your linked question, is trying to execute docker commands from PHP. Whereas I am trying to run SASS.

Comment: @Starx You're welcome. I figured that you may have also had to pass another variable inside the command as Jay had to do, that's why I thought it may have been of help.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, Yes I get that. These things are different for different executables. Mine is yet to be figured out.

Comment: @Starx I understand. Did you Google that (first) error? (`undefined method `\``+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`) There are a few hits for it, maybe there's something in some of the Q&A's here on Stack that may lead you to find the problem.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, I have referred to those :)

Comment: It looks like in your container you're running `sass` as root. `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` will tell you who your PHP user is, and then you can try running `sass` as that user to see if there are any permission issues.

Comment: @AndréDion, Well if a script is executable, any user can execute it. But thanks for your help, I managed to figure out the problem. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I manage to figure the problem out. The `sass` requires a home directory to operate correctly. If you are executing PHP as a system user, which in my case it was, it does not have a home directory, that is why it failed.

On Linux, you can use `mkhomedir_helper [user]` to create a home directory. Once you have created a home directory, `sass` will start to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem earlier, when I tried to run grunt from inside a PHP script. It turned out, the problem was the missing environment variables.

So if you could execute your sass command in the bash, but it doesn't work from inside the php script, the following could help you solve your problem.

To list your current environment vars, you could use the unix command `printenv`. This should give you a list like the following

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
rvm_bin_path=/usr/local/rvm/bin
rvm_version=1.26.11 (latest)
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.2.1
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
...
```

As scss uses ruby, it is important to have all the ruby env vars available. So you could pick everything you need from printenvs output and write it inside an array.

```
$env = [
    "LANG" => "en_US.UTF-8",
    "rvm_bin_path" => "/usr/local/rvm/bin",
    ...
];
$env_command = '';
foreach ($env as $var => $value) {
    $env_command .= "$var=$value ";
}

$command = "/usr/local/bin/sass ...";

exec "$env_command $command";
```

I'm not sure, which vars are actual important - so you have to figure this out on your own.

Comment: I am trying to get environment variables similar to yours, but I am getting `HOSTNAME=435f9c1b57ba
TERM=xterm
OLDPWD=/var/www/html/portal
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01
PATH=/usr/local/php/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/var/www/html/portal/web/styles
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LESSOPEN=
_=/usr/bin/printenv`

Comment: I didn't think anything other than `PATH` would be relevant, so I tried with that, and that didn't bring any change.

Comment: Are you sure, scss is actually working inside your container? And how did you execute printenv? With php or from the console?